# Mongodb: Get avg duration of products in inventory

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with $vehicleId and $Scraped Date. I am trying to get the avg days a car is in inventory. And I want to calculate it for all the historical days.

Sample Doc

```html
{"_id":{"$oid":"5e1b46d853848fae2832e01a"},"Scraped Date":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1578845911324"}},"vehicleId":{"$numberInt":"1376788"}}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5e1b46d853848fae2832e01b"},"Scraped Date":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1578845911324"}},"vehicleId":{"$numberInt":"1376771"}}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5e1b46d853848fae2832e01c"},"Scraped Date":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1578845911324"}},"vehicleId":{"$numberInt":"1376734"}}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5e1b46d853848fae2832e01d"},"Scraped Date":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1578845911324"}},"vehicleId":{"$numberInt":"1376706"}}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5e1b46d853848fae2832e01e"},"Scraped Date":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1578845911324"}},"vehicleId":{"$numberInt":"1376505"}}
```

```html
collection.aggregate([
    {'$group': {
        '_id' : {'vehicleId': '$vehicleId'},
        'date' : {'$addToSet': "$Scraped Date"}
    } }
    ]
)
```

This code is giving me a list of dates the vehicleId was found in the inventory. How can I convert this to list of dates with avg length the cars were in inventory for that day?  I could think of finding the avg length of the dates column but that wont give the me the data day wise.

The current output looks like this in a dataframe:

[dataframe view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txbEh.png)

Comment: How do you calculate  manually the _"avg days a car is in inventory"_ with the available sample docs?

Comment: @Prasad_ so if you look at the dataframe image that I have attached. It has vehicle id and all the dates vehicle was found in inventory. I am just calculating the total days each car is in inventory simply by using python and then taking their avg.

Comment: I figured out a solution. Created a simple for loop for every date and then used the $match query to first filter the results and then calculate the avg length. The question is closed for now. I will update the code in the original question in a while.

Comment: So the field `datetime.datetime` is an array of dates for each vehicle (and a vehicle can have different number of date/time elements)?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution. Created a simple for loop for every date and then used the $match query to first filter the results and then calculate the avg length. The question is closed for now. I will update the code in the original question in a while